# Linq (groupBy?) question

Tags: c#, linq

i have a collection of `Order` objects, and each `Order` object has 1 or more `Card` objects in it (in a `generic List object called Cards`.

Now i want to know the total number of cards, in one number.

I'm not getting it together, and the Linq intellisense just doesn't makes any sense for me....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the number of Cards using

```
yourCollection.Sum(o => o.Cards.Count);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int totalCount = orders.Sum(order => order.Cards.Count);
```

Answer (score 2):

May be cards are null:

```
orders.Sum(p => p.Cards == null?0:p.Cards.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let you have:

```
class Order
{
     public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
IEnumerable<Order> orders = ..
int cards = orders.Sum(o => o.Cards.Count);
```